# How to Redirect a non-www to www with Mutiple Sites? (Nginx and Varnish)

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, varnish

First I want to clarify that I searched a lot about this issue, but I haven't found a solution.

I have 2 Wordpress sites configured under the same Nginx (port 8080) and Varnish (port 80).

This is my actual setting:

```
map $http_host $blogid {
 default 0;
 www.site1.com 1;
 www.site2.com 2;
}
server {
 listen 8080;
 server_name www.site1.com site1.com;
 root /var/www/site1.com;
 ...
}
server {
 listen 8080;
 server_name www.site2.com site2.com;
 root /var/www/site2.com;
 ...
}
```

What I want to do, is to configure a redirect for site2 from a non-www to a www. Example: http://site2.com -> http://www.site2.com

I added another '*server*' configuration with the redirect, and let just '*www.site2.com*' in the other '*server_name*'.

```
map $http_host $blogid {
 default 0;
 www.site1.com 1;
 www.site2.com 2;
}
server {
 server_name www.site1.com site1.com;
 root /var/www/site1.com;
 ...
}
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name site2.com;
    return 301 http://www.site2.com$request_uri;
}
server {
 server_name www.site2.com;
 root /var/www/site2.com;
 ...
}
```

After changed with the configuration above and restarting Nginx, what happened is when accessing "http://site2.com" (without www) it is loading the content from  "http://site1.com" (url continues site2.com without www). Acessing "http://www.site2.com" shows the right content.

What I'm doing wrong?

I think that redirect is not working because I tried to redirect to Google.com, but it didn't redirect. It keeps loading "site1.com" content inside "site2.com".

```
return 301 http://www.google.com
```

I tried this code below, but with the same result:

```
rewrite ^(.*) http://www.site2.com$1 permanent;
```

My complete **Nginx configuration**:
http://codepad.org/TfPHS0jH

Comment: Why do you have the map code added? Since it doesn't do anything in your example configuration?? Could you have missed something out of the sample code?

Comment: Hi @Dayo, I left that configuration there because I don't know if that could interferer. This is my complete NginX configuration: http://codepad.org/TfPHS0jH

Comment: The link you gave returns a 500 server error

Comment: Here it is: http://pastie.org/private/yzcqqt6thmt6jvxmmlvuhw  (I'm pasting in another server, because the file is too big)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time, this was my solution:

http://www.softprayog.in/troubleshooting/how-to-redirect-non-www-urls-to-www-in-varnish

Answer (score 0):

Your site isn't being served by Nginx but by Varnish.

When you navigate to any of http://www.siteX.com or http://siteX.com, you are going to http://www.siteX.com:80 or http://siteX.com:80 and according to your explanation, Varnish listens on Port 80, not Nginx.

There is no real reason to ever have to use the two together (despite what you may have read on some websites) and you should get rid or one or the other and focus on the one you decide to keep.

Comment: Correct, my website is beign served by Varnish. But the first request goes to Nginx, as there is nothing in cache. So, in this case, the problem is using both? Are there any workaround?

Comment: The first request goes to Varnish since it listens on Port 80 which is the default port. This is why the redirection in Nginx does not work. The request never gets to Nginx at all. There is always a workaround but why implement an unnecessarily complicated setup and then start working around it?